# Launch Skype from Android App programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, skype

I create a call directly using the default os dialer by:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNo));
startActivity(call);
```

Is it possible to launch Skype directly from my app?

I try to pass a number as follows:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
Intent skype = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.raider");
skype.setData(Uri.parse("tel:65465446"));
startActivity(skype);
```

Passing the number fails.

Comment: ..thanks for your question which help me ..i have one doubt that how could we get the package name for the particular app

Comment: maybe looking at logcat can help when you are running that app in the device and device is connected to eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Skype from an App Programmatically & Pass Number - Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-an-app-programmatically-pass-number-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know Skype package name (something like: com.skype.android), then you can start it:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.android"));
```

Comment: possible skype package name: `com.skype.raider`

Comment: It worked but I also need to pass phone no. to skype. I tried as... in the question