# How to start Viber call from an Android app?

Tags: android, skype, phone-call, viber

I am developing an Android application, and besides other functionalities it has to be able to place a call using Viber. I tried to use [solution for Skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132556/how-to-start-a-skype-call-from-an-android-app) but without success. Error which I get is:

```
05-08 19:51:51.660: D/AndroidRuntime(29140): Shutting down VM
05-08 19:51:51.660: W/dalvikvm(29140): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=viber:0692155555 }
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1409)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at rs.stanar.pantaxinovisad.MainActivity.call(MainActivity.java:61)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at rs.stanar.pantaxinovisad.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:117)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-08 19:51:51.680: E/AndroidRuntime(29140):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code of my app that I am trying to use to invoke Viber is:

```
public void call(String dialNumber) {
        Intent viber = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        viber.setData(Uri.parse("viber:" + dialNumber));
        startActivity(viber);
    }

  <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="viber" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter
            android:priority="0" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
```

**What should I do in order to make this work?**

Comment: Looks like that Viber does not handle this intent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem was resolved with this piece of code:

```
public void call(String dialNumber) {
    try{
    Intent callIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + dialNumber));
    startActivity(callIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + dialNumber));
        startActivity(callIntent);
    }
}
```

where this was crucial: **"android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"**

After applying this, new window was opened offering for call to be made by all possible means for placing call - in this particular case, they were Dialer and Viber and Skype (or any other method added later).

Answer (score 6):

If you want to start Viber explicitly to call specific phone number:

```
Intent localIntent4 = new Intent("com.viber.voip.action.CALL");
localIntent4.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.viber.voip.call");
localIntent4.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number_to_call));
localIntent4.putExtra("external_call", true);
localIntent4.putExtra("contact_id", -1L);
startActivity(localIntent4);
```

All you need to do is to initialize variable **phone_number_to_call** as you wish.