# How open Viber public chat from Android app?

Tags: android, xamarin, viber

I have Android app. I need open Viber public chat from my app. The numbers for this chat are not in the user's phonebook.Is it possible?

I have not found information about this. Just a few old questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following code (from [**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189221/how-to-open-viber-public-chat-from-android-app)):

```
var viberPackageName = "com.viber.voip";
var phone = "5757575757";

try
{
    StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("viber://add?number=$phone")));
}
catch
{
    try
    {
        StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("market://details?id=$viberPackageName")));
    }
    catch
    {
        StartActivity(new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$viberPackageName")));
    }
 }
```