# Android lauch skype for business and make a call with specified skypeID

Tags: android, android-intent, skype, skype-for-business

On clicking on a textview with skypeID, the application should launch skype for business(lync) and start a call with the specified skypeID, i'm able to launch the app but not start the call option automatically? i was able to do it in skype but not in skype for business(lync), could you kindly suggest me how to do it?
TIA

Comment: This may help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skype-for-business-uris/androidcall

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void skype(String number, Context ctx) {
    try {
        //Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED");
        //the above line tries to create an intent for which the skype app doesn't supply public api

            Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
        sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + number));
        Log.d("UTILS", "tel:" + number);
        ctx.startActivity(sky);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e("SKYPE CALL", "Skype failed", e);
    }

}
```

I didn't try this, please try and check. for more info go to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132556/how-to-start-a-skype-call-from-an-android-app)

Comment: Hi, this works fine for skype but not for skype for business(lync).

Comment: oh, I'll check on that, and update if I get something :)