# Android skype intent to automatically make a call

Tags: android, android-intent, skype, auto

I'm trying to develop an applicaton in which a part makes a call to skype without further user input. Following snippet does not place the call itself, but only takes me to the skype contact-page. I still have to push the call button. What can I do to make the call automatically? I already request the CALL_PHONE permissions.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + contactId + "?call"));
        startActivity(intent);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this maybe it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132556/how-to-start-a-skype-call-from-an-android-app. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please check in skype developer doc. 
They provides Mobile SDK and APIs for skype call. 
Please refer [Microsoft doc for Starting a call from an Android mobile device For Business](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skype-for-business-uris/androidcall).

```
Button skypeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
   final EditText SIPAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.SIPAddress) ;
   final CheckBox videoCall = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.videoCheck);
   skypeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           String uriString = "ms-sfb://call?id="+SIPAddress.getText().toString();
           if (videoCall.isChecked()){
               uriString +="&video=true";
           }
           Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString);
           Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
           startActivity(callIntent);
       }
   } );
```

And for [Skype SDK for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypesdkforandroid) as per doc you can call using that.

```
try { 
SkypeApi skypeApi = new SkypeApi(getApplicationContext()); 

    skypeApi.startConversation(skypeName.toString(), 
     Modality.AudioCall); 
  } catch (SkypeSdkException e) { 
    // Exception handling logic here 
}
```

You can also use URI to call for these refer this link [Skype URI tutorial: Android apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_androidapps) and answer [How to start a Skype call from an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61245298/6041365)

Comment: Hello, that's for Skype for business. My question handles the normal skype (which is not the same)

Comment: Okay. I updated answer. Can you check and let me know. I added a link also so It may helpful to you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61245298/6041365 here also mention answer for skype calling using URI

Comment: I followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype-sdk/skypeuris/skypeuritutorial_androidapps but my example code above is mapping that too. It brings me to a screen, where i still need to say I want to connect. So my question is, is there anybody who uses is and where it's working?

Comment: I just found out it has something todo with the skype version itself. With Skype V8.15.0.430 it works as intended. Only in later versions, somewhere it dropped this auto-call functionality or something. Who should we ask? Are there change-notes available somewhere?