# How to trigger Skype SMS out?

Tags: android, skype

I learned how to trigger a Skype OUT call [Launch Skype from an App Programmatically & Pass Number - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-pass-number-android/8844526#8844526)

Is there a way to trigger a Skype OUT SMS?