# Android program to log in to skype automatically?

Tags: java, android, service, automation, skype

I am going to make a small android app for myself that automatically logs into skype at 8:00am every morning. The question I have for you all is, what code do I use to go into the skype app, enter in my hardcoded username/password, and sign in? Is there a different method to doing this? Any information will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: how are you planning to enter the Skype account credentials automatically? Did you implement auto login feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could download the skype app and log into it. Then every morning at 8, use AlarmManager to  start the intent used by the skype app so that skype is automatically started.

AlarmManager reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

You can use this to launch the intent for skype:

```
PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.android"));
```

another name for this package could be `"com.skype.raider"`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad. But here is a starting reference how to start Skype through an intent and pass in username [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-pass-number-android)
After that I suggest you research how to set up a background service and create a timer.