# How can I start a Google Hangout in Android with an Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I want to make an simple app that can start a google+ hangout with a selected google+ circle. Is there a way to call an intent to start a google hangout?

Comment: I dont think there is currently any way to create a Google+ hangout on an android device using an intent or any other API. However you could request that feature here :) (http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/entry)

Comment: That's odd, skype supports it. Please comment/support the feature request: http://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=405

Comment: @tommychheng Can you please show how to do it for Skype? can it offer opening a chat with a specific person, using phone-number, email, or contact id ? Can it also add text so that all the user needs to do is press "send" ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-an-app-programmatically-pass-number-android/8844526#8844526