# How to video call a user through skype from another android application?

Tags: android, call, skype

I am very new for this android application development and I am learning. This question might look very easy but I am unable to find a solution. I am posting my code..

```
    Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.ACTION_VIEW");
    skype.setClassName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main");
    skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:echo123?call")); 
    this.startActivity(skype);
```

I got this from referring to the link [Launch Skype from an App Programmatically & Pass Number - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-pass-number-android/8844526#8844526). I have tried everything on that page. From the above code, I am able to start the skype but am NOT able to start the call..  Please help me on what I am missing out..!!

Answer (score 1):

Try This, for video call to a specific user:

```
Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + "UserName"+ "?call&video=true"));
startActivity(sky);
```

Comment: But...how to make call directly outside from of a activity...please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "outside of an activity"? Do you mean from a Service? usually you just need a context to use intents