# call a number using skype in android and need to get skype contact list

Tags: java, android

I am making an app where I need to make a video call using `Skype`. Can anyone help me? The code I wrote so far is:

```
Intent sky = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
sky.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + playerChanged + "?call&video=true"));
sky.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
sky.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(sky);
```

but this code did nothing except open the `Skype` app.

I need to fetch my skype contact list...

Comment: go to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-pass-number-android?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

try to do the following :

```
Intent skypeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
skypeIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
skypeIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.skype.raider", "com.skype.raider.Main"));
skypeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(skypeIntent);
```

hope that helps .