# How to Import, use or initiat Skype video conferencing in android

Tags: android, video, skype

Greeting,

I want to develop an android app which will initiate a video call (multi call) by using Skype. How to do that?

I used the Skype URI but it doesn't help since the android app do not support initiating/hosting group video calls. Please check the below link under the section "Video Call" for more information. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745882.aspx

Therefor, is there another way to make my android app make a conference call through Skype?

Thanks,
Ziad

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to hand code that functionality in your app, you could simply "ask" the Skype app to make the call for you.

You do this by starting the Skype application and passing in the appropriate Extras with your intent.

This code was reported to have worked in Skype 4.0 on android.

```
Intent skype = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
skype.setData(Uri.parse("skype:" + user_name));
startActivity(skype);
```

See: [Launch Skype from an App Programmatically & Pass Number - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414494/launch-skype-from-an-app-programmatically-pass-number-android?rq=1)

It's worth noting that if Microsoft/Skype team changes the kind of intent filters that the Skype app accepts, the code will no longer work. So your mileage may very across versions and updates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can the Skype URI enable my developed android app to initiate a video call through Skype which include more than two participants in the same conference? Based on my understanding that Skype URI will only allow my android to initiate a video call for two participants only. Please check the below link under the section "Video Call" for more information. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn745882.aspx

Comment: I need to add that I did use Skype URI in android and it works with two participants, however, when I add more participants the Skype ignore the rest and accept the first two participants in the URI.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, currently, Skype URI can not initiate a group video call with more than two participants (in Android).

for hangouts, currently, it doesn't provide API for Android developers.

therefore, I built my application by using ooVoo video chat SDK. The SDK allows me to import the video chat(12 participants) in my application. Chick this link for more information https://developers.oovoo.com/docs.

If you want to find other vendors that can provide you with a video chat SDK, go to this link https://bloggeek.me/missing-webrtc-paas-report/

thanks,
z