# Can I link Skype with my Android App?

Tags: java, android, sip, voip, skype

I want to add VoIP functionality to my application, without developing required VoIP/SIP libraries myself. Is it possible to "link" Skype to my application? Maybe via a button, which starts Skype?
Otherwise, are there any open source code projects for Android VoIP/SIP available (such as SipDroid?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [VOIP open source project](http://sipdroid.org/) and it uses google voice as well, and there may be others, if you want to [launch skype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405434/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-android) you will need to use an intent, maybe answered here as well [Skype Intent](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=366611) and you may be able to [google android skype and intent](http://%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B1%5D%5Benter%20link%20description%20here%5D%5B2%5D) if none of that works