# Start android application from code

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I need simple start an application from my code, like Skype, or other one.
I read some thread, on the internet, but I haven't  solution. 
I tried this methode:

```
Intent startApp = new Intent("com.android.gesture.builder");
startActivity(startApp);
```

I wrote this in try/catch blokk, and the LogCat told me: ApplicationNotFound exception handled by Intent. I read the "Hello" tutorial on the Android Developers site, but it's too comlicated, to my solution...
I can't register this application starting activity to my manifest file.
I think I need to implement a new class, that extends from Activity, and implement, the code above, and try again?
Please help me, how can I start other application from my main activity easy...

Comment: This is a very thorough question. Good work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were nearly there!:

You just need to supply the package and class of the app you want.

```
// Try
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.htc.Camera", "com.htc.Camera.Camera"));
startActivity(intent);
// catch not found (only works on HTC phones)
```

[ComponentName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html)

I also just saw you can do it a second way:

```
  PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
  startActivity(packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.skype.android"));
```

See: [SOQ Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405434/launch-skype-from-the-app-programetically-android/6405522#6405522)

Comment: I like your second way! It's working for me, thank you very much :)